# Basic Angular app using ui-router won't load login

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a POC for work and I can't find whatever stupid mistake is hiding here. I have a bare-bones/basic angular app, using ui-router. Plunker can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/a2lYNyktpqsLhmNDX1a8?p=preview).

In the chrome console I can see my app.module is being created, however the login page never appears. This is a very, very basic app so I figure it must be something simple I'm missing. Any suggestions? Below is a quick sample:

**config.js**

```
(function() {
'use strict'
var app = angular.module('app.core');
app.config(AppRouter);
AppRouter.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

function AppRouter($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('login');
  $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    })
    .state('login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
    });
}
})();
```

**login.controller.js**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app.login');

app.controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$location', '$filter', '$window', '$rootScope'];

function LoginController($location, $filter, $window, $rootScope) {
  var init = function() {
    console.log('here');
  };

  init();
}
})();
```

**app.module.js**

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', ['app.core', 'app.login']);
})();
```

**login.module.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict'
    var app = angular.module('app.login', ['app.core']);
})();
```

**core.module.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict'
    var app = angular.module('app.core', ['ui.router']);
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few changes it worked for me (see forked plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/D5AL8DTnqYI2g23wjE7W?p=preview):

You forgot to load AngularJS (between `<head></head`).
You forgot to add `ng-app`, I add it on body.
And I made some changes in `config.js`:

```
function AppRouter($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
      .state('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
      });
  }
```

I add `url` to `login` state, and I made changes to `otherwise` function: I changed `login` to `/login` cause it needs URL, not state name.
I think you *overconfigured* you app a little bit (too much modules), and it makes it hard to read for me, but it's only my opinion and to be frankly, maybe it's only because I don't use modules very frequently. Try to add this changes to your Plunk and please write if it won't work, casue I could accidentally skip something.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. Lesson learned - start small :)

Comment: @NealR I am glad to hear it :)